# The expression contains an escape sequence

Tags: asp.net, regex, url, url-rewriting

I am using rewrite module to allow double quotes in string

```
[_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\22\42.]
```

But it gives the following error.

**The expression "^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\22\42.]+)" contains an escape sequence that is not valid.**

Comment: You might have missed `\x`. Use `\x22` and `\x42`. Or use `\u0022` and `\u0042`. You might also need to double the backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\22` and `\42` are not valid *escape sequences*. You need to specify the hex notation if you plan to match those characters:

```
[_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\u0022\u0042.]
```

Or

```
[_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\x22\x42.]
```

Comment: My url contain ""(double quotes) so how can i allow it sir?

Comment: Show where (how) you are using the regex.

Comment: I am using URL rewrite rule to allow double quotes in url 
here is the pattern
" <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\u0022\u0042.]+)"/>"


and I have to allow URL like this
"localhost:8007/News/4330/"Polling-gewend-aan-favorietenrol"

Comment: Try adding `[A-Z]` to the first group: `^([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([_0-9A-Za-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~\`\x22\x42.]+)`, or make the regex case-insensitive (if there is an option).

Comment: If it does not work like that, check if the `^` (anchoring the pattern at the start of the stirng) is really needed. Maybe you just need to remove it and add the `$` at the end (if you need to just check the 3 last parts separated with `/`.

Comment: <match url="([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([_0-9A-Za-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\x22\x42.]+)$"/>
just like this 

but still not allowing ""

Comment: Please add the whole relevant code to the question. Also, I think there may be a `/` at the beginning, try `^/([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([_0-9A-Za-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~\`\x22\x42.]+)$`.

Comment: Ok this one <rule name="Rewrite URL for Three Query String">
          <match url="([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)/([_0-9A-Za-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\x22\x42.]+)$"/>

Thsi url can allow the url which have 3 query string.

Comment: These parts you capture are not query strings. Query string is what comes after `?` and there is only 1 query string. Please check http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module